# How to fix blurry VS2019

Tags: rendering, visual-studio-2019, display

I ran into an issue where my second monitor with decent resolution, was showing a poorly rendered VS2019.
Disclaimer: If somebody would port the features I need in VS2019 to VSCode that'd be great.

Anyway, here is a pic that sums up my issue and since I had to comb through the annoyingly fixed-but-not-fixed, yet locked, tickets on MS to find clues to my answer I'm sharing here.
Here is my secondary, 27" monitor, with poor rendering. This happens to be the ONLY program that does this... VSCode looks great and is readable, Outlook, Gimp, they all look fine. Only VS2019 is giving my eyes pain.

[image: Blurry on secondary monitor]

Main/Built-in Monitor looks just fine though. I'd prefer to work with more screen space though.
[image: Fine on main monitor]

Answer (score 11):

In VS2019 GOTO: Tools > Options >> Environment > General, and look for "Optimize rendering..." Note: This screenshot is from after I'd found and applied the the fix.
[image: Where to find Optimize Rendering]

It will be grayed-out and unselected if requirements are not met by your system, along with a message, "Requires NET 4.8 and Windows 10 minimum build 1803". I then mistakenly installed NET 4.8, and nothing changed (and the checkbox was still locked indicating requirements were not met).
More searching lead me to the 4.8 Dev Pack. Here is a link to it:

[NET 4.8 Developer Pack](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2088517)

Finally, after another reboot, I opened up VS2019 and the rendering looks something like modern... and the checkbox automatically checked itself.

Comment: Also worked for Visual Studio 2022, thanks

Comment: Also worked on VS 2023, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For me the accepted answer didn't change anythig, turns out it was caused by scaling on Windows (on main monitor it was set to 125%), after changing it to 100% everything looks normal

Answer (score -1):

For me, I just move the VS window to the blurry monitor. Close VS. Open VS again and all looks good.